# How do I set or freeze time in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, python-datetime

I want to set a fixed time using python different than that seen locally on my system , so that when I used datetime.date.today() I get to see the desired date

Comment: Try [freezegun](https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/).

Comment: Just mock `datetime.date.today` and configure the `return_value` to what you want. The `freezegun` module looks quite useful if your freezing needs start to extend to many other `datetime` calls too.

Answer (score 11):

Add argument tz_offset. See the doc https://pypi.org/project/freezegun/

```py
from freezegun import freeze_time

@freeze_time("2012-01-14 03:21:34", tz_offset=-4)
def test():
    assert datetime.datetime.utcnow() == datetime.datetime(2012, 1, 14, 3, 21, 34)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use pytz package with datetime,
And assign to date time now.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

# add wanted timezone instead of America/New_York
timeZone_AN = pytz.timezone('America/New_York') 
dt_Ny = datetime.now(timeZone_AN)
print("Datetime: ", dt_Ny)
```

updated according to [MrFuppes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/mrfuppes) comment, as pytz will be deprecated you can use zoneinfo.
it seems like it will be more useful than pytz.

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
timeZone_AN=("America/New_York")
```

**update**

If you want to get a fixed datetime then this will help you.

```
# set your date as year, month, day
desiredTime_ymd = datetime.date(2020, 9,14) 

#print to test 
print(desiredTime_ymd)

#set sec, min, hour
desiredTime_smh=time(14, 42, 59)


#print to test 
print(desiredTime_smh)

#set all at once
#datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
desredTime_all = datetime(2020, 9,14, 14, 42, 59)

#print to test 
print(desiredTime_all)
```

Comment: will be [deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/) - use dateutil or zoneinfo (Py3.9) instead.

Comment: I do not want to change the timezone or print anything. I just want to change the time itself without using freezegun

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to easily do it without relying on something like `freezegun`. If it was trivial to do, then `freezegun` likely wouldn't exist.

Comment: if you want a specific datetime then you can set in datetime.date itself, I just updated answer.